# docx4j generate PDF with mail merge fields

Tags: java, ms-word, docx4j, mailmerge

i am using Docx4j to generate pdf documents based on Microsoft Word templates.

In a microsoft word template, i have some Mail Merge fields, which should be replaced.
I am able to replace Mail Merge field but in generated PDF are displayed in a wrong way.

In output PDF i have always text like MERGEFIELD ContractNo * MERGEFORMAT.
In word, you can swith between field views by ALT+F9, but how can i achieve to show in generate PDF different view of mail merge fields?

Instead of MERGEFIELD ContractNo * MERGEFORMAT i want to show only ContractNo.

Answer (score 0):

Should "just work" with a current nightly build (as opposed to 2.8.1).

Answer (score -1):

Use Content Controls instead of MERGEFIELDs. I've posted an example on github complete with a sample template and a sample XML data file: https://github.com/sylnsr/docx4j-ws ...
MergeFields are [deprecated](http://www.docx4java.org/docx4j/Docx4j_GettingStarted.pdf) and not (IMHO) recommended for continued use.